# Can google Chrome can block the creation of the csrf token?

Tags: javascript, cookies, csrf, sessionid, csrf-token

Can google Chrome can block the creation of the `csrftoken`?
To be precise, the csfrtoken and the sessionId are absent from the developer console.
However, both (always for the same site) are visible on the firefox console. Why ?

```
getCookie('csrftoken');

function getCookie(name) {
    const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
    const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
    if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
}
```

**EDIT**

on google chrome there are only these 2 warnings:

**Image "country:__" could not be loaded. Please make sure you have added the image with map.addImage() or a "sprite" property in your style. You can provide missing images by listening for the "styleimagemissing" map event.**

**LogRocket: Session quota exceeded. Please upgrade your plan. Disabling ...**

---

But on firefox there is also this warning:

**Some cookies use the "SameSite" attribute recommended incorrectly**

Comment: my first thought is that chrome is rejecting the cookie (NOT because it's a csrftoken or sessionId, as cookie names are arbitrary and have no special meanings) - check the developer tools console for any warnings/errors/issues with cookies - specifically issues with cookie "SameSite" attribute

Comment: @Bravo yes are the warnings....see the edit

Comment: @Bravo the strange thing is that the two cookies are not visible even on Opera. Only visible on firefox and explorer. How is it possible ?

Comment: Both forefox and Chrume (including Edge) have been warning about misuse or lack of SameSite attribute on cookies for some time, and that these cookies *will be ignored in the future* - clearly, Chrume has now reached that point, and Firefox has not - it's still issuing warnings - the site owner needs to fix how cookies are set on the server

Comment: @Bravo with firefox i can read SAMEORIGIN attribute....

Comment: No idea what you mean - I'm talking about browsers actively rejecting cookies - which seems to be your issue - not about what some random sameorigin attribute - which is not the same word as samesite ... see ... samesite vs sameorigin